# Consume Web Services in Camel

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-camel

I have a WSDL file that describes a Web Service. There is however no implementation yet, but I created a Mock Service in SoapUI which is hard-coded to give the same response over and over again.

I want Camel to send a SOAP request from disk to the web service, and write the response to another file. I was thinking the routes could look like this:

```
from(file:data/input/soaprequest)
.to(wsendpoint)

from(wsendpoint)
.to(file:data/input/soapresponse)
```

And then I addded both of them to the camel context and I'm not sure if that's the correct way, but even if it is, I am still struggling with setting up the webserviceendpoint. Since I can't use Spring XML, this is what I have :

```
CxfEndpoint wsendpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
wsendpoint.setAddress("http://localhost:9001/HelloWorld");
wsendpoint.setWsdlURL("http://localhost:9001/HelloWorld?WSDL");
wsendpoint.setServiceClass("com.generated.HelloWorld");
wsendpoint.setCamelContext(camelcontext);
```

And then I pass wsendpoint to the route as you can see above. But nothing is happening. The application never stops, it doesn't post any response in the output folder, it just says

```
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:9001/HelloWorld
```

I also tried sending the request from SoapUI while the application is still running and it changes nothing in the application and I get a 404 error in SoapUI

Answer (score 2):

The route should be like this

```
from(file:data/input/soaprequest)
   .to(wsendpoint)
   .to(file:data/input/soapresponse)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your task something like the following:

```
 <!--Configure SOAP endpoint in camel-->
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="cxfEndpoint"
                     serviceClass="SEIClassNameHere"
                     address="exposedAdress">
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

  <!--Configure consuming camel route-->
    <route id="consumingFromCXFEndpointRoute">
            <from uri="cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint"/>
            <to uri="file:someFile"/>
    </route> 

  <!--Configure producing camel route-->
    <route id="producingToCXFEndpointRoute">
            <from uri="timer://foo?period=60000"/>
            <pollEnrich uri="file:{{sourceFolder}}?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&amp;move=  {{destinationFolder}}/${file:name}-${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmssSSS}.csv&amp;moveFailed= {{errorFolder}}/${file:name}-${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmssSSS}.csv"
                    timeout="5000"/>
            <to uri="cxf:serviceAddress?serviceClass=SEIClassNameHere&defaultOperationName=methodYouWantToCall"/>
    </route>
```

Comment: I think it's getting there. I still get this: ERROR processing exchange. Exchange[Message: [Body is null]]. Caused by ..blabla.. GenericFile cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Camel tries to convert exchange body to string before sending it to cxf component and by default it can not do conversion. That's why you have to implement your own transformer which will transform the file content to the desired data type your cxf service accept as the method argument.

Comment: How do you provide your parameters if the parameters are more than one?

Comment: What for do you need more then one parameter?? the file representing request for a remote service
already contains soap body with all required parameters for a particular method invocation.